# flexible discriminant analysis computational completixy

Tags: r, caret

I'm using mda package + caret infrastucture to perform a flexible discriminant analysis for a classification problems. I have 26 features of mixed type. I found little if any guidance on the computational time. How does it vary as a function of both predictors and dataset size?

Comment: Be aware that CV has become a lot more strict about questions concerning software. You should be cautious about that. That said, the time complexity of an analysis (eg FDA) could be on topic here.

Comment: I voted to leave this open on the grounds that it's *not* about using Caret per se, but actually about the computational complexity of FDA algorithm.

Comment: What parameters in fda are worth tuning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this document](http://www.milbo.org/doc/earth-notes.pdf):

> "2.6 Execution time
>
> For a given set of input data, the following can increase the speed of the forward pass:
>
> (i) decreasing `degree` (because there are fewer combinations of terms to consider),
>
> (ii) decreasing `nk` (because there are fewer forward pass terms),
>
> (iii) increasing `minspan` (because fewer knots need to be considered),
>
> (iv) decreasing `fast.k` (because there are fewer potential parents to consider at each forward step),
>
> (v) increasing `thresh` (faster if there are fewer forward pass terms).
>
> The backward pass is normally much faster than the forward pass, unless `method = "exhaustive"`. Reducing `prune` reduces exhaustive search time. One strategy is to first build a large model and then adjust pruning parameters such as `prune` using `update.earth`."

(Note that `train` uses the strategy with `update.earth` when `train`'s `method = "earth"` but *not* when `method = "fda"` so technical reasons related to how MARS is bundled into FDA.)

Otherwise, it depends on your data size, number and types of predictors etc. The document linked above does have formulas for memory usage and that might be an acceptable proxy.

Max